# Join two lists into one row-wise

Tags: python, list, merge

I have two lists and need to join them by rows. The output looks like list3 (below). Actually there aren't any commas between the bracketed pairs. I've tried a few different things and can't figure this out.

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [4, 5, 6]
```

my desired output is:  `list3 = [[1 4], [2 5], [3 6]]`

Comment: take a look at `zip`...

Comment: your output is illegal python

Comment: did you mean `list3 = [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]` with a `,` inside each of the list items? You cannot have a list item without comma and two numbers separated by space. If they need to be separated by space, then it has to be a string. That will result in `[['1 4'], ['2 5'],['3 6']]`

Comment: Also, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read how to ask good [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure your question covers these 3 elements: 1. Problem Statement 2. Your Code (it should be [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 3. Error Message (preferably full Traceback to help others review and provide feedback).

Comment: Thanks, Joe! I'm still figuring it all out, but will get better.

Answer (score 1):

Use zip

```
[[i, j] for i,j in zip(list1 , list1 )]
```

`[[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]`

Comment: Thanks, Kenan. It worked, but there are commas between everything. The result I should get doesn't seem to have any commas between the pairs. I shouldn't have put those in there in my original post.

Comment: It looks like: [[1 4] [2 5] [3 6]]

Comment: so you want the list to have strings? `[['1 4']...`

Comment: `[list(i) for i in zip(list1 , list2)]` , second one is `list2`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you want the final list to be list of lists or not but I will assume you do,

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3] 
list2 = [4, 5, 6]
res = [[*np.asarray([list1, list2])[:,i]] for i in range(3)]
res = [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```